# If non-zero cosmological constant interpreted as a repulsive field, what would be the properties of this field's quanta?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, cosmology, particle-physics, cosmological-constant

If non-zero cosmological constant interpreted as a repulsive field, what would be the properties of the excitation of such field, i.e. the particle which serves as the field's quantum?

What would be its spin, mass, possible interactions and other properties?

Comment: not a common interpretation. Most people don't treat dark energy as having a particle. I'm interested to see what answers you get

Answer (score 2):

I am sorry to disappoint you that cosmological ***constant*** is not a ***dynamical field*** in usual GR sense. Therefore no quantization can be done.

However, there were a lot of interesting attempts to interpret the cosmological constant in other way. One of the famous example is [DGP theory of gravity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DGP_model). Roughly a scalar is introduced in the theory such that the effects of this scalar is repulsive in long enough distance. In this way, it plays the role of cosmological constant and thus the cosmological constant is not needed to explain the accelerated expansion of the universe.

Also, there are other theories of ***massive gravity*** even trying to explain dark matter without the need of dark matter.